# Validate a codice fiscale

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem

## Validate a codice fiscale

Every Italian resident/citizen is given a 16-character alphanumeric [*codice fiscale*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italian_fiscal_code)

### Challenge

The final letter is a check code, which is calculated as follows :

- Characters of the code are split up into even and odd character according to their positions (check letter excluded)
- Both sets are replaced according to the following tables :

| ODD CHARACTERS (1st, 3rd...) |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Character | Value | Character | Value | Character | Value | Character | Value |
| 0 | 1 | 9 | 21 | I | 19 | R | 8 |
| 1 | 0 | A | 1 | J | 21 | S | 12 |
| 2 | 5 | B | 0 | K | 2 | T | 14 |
| 3 | 7 | C | 5 | L | 4 | U | 16 |
| 4 | 9 | D | 7 | M | 18 | V | 10 |
| 5 | 13 | E | 9 | N | 20 | W | 22 |
| 6 | 15 | F | 13 | O | 11 | X | 25 |
| 7 | 17 | G | 15 | P | 3 | Y | 24 |
| 8 | 19 | H | 17 | Q | 6 | Z | 23 |

| EVEN CHARACTERS (2nd, 4th...) |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Character | Value | Character | Value | Character | Value | Character | Value |
| 0 | 0 | 9 | 9 | I | 8 | R | 17 |
| 1 | 1 | A | 0 | J | 9 | S | 18 |
| 2 | 2 | B | 1 | K | 10 | T | 19 |
| 3 | 3 | C | 2 | L | 11 | U | 20 |
| 4 | 4 | D | 3 | M | 12 | V | 21 |
| 5 | 5 | E | 4 | N | 13 | W | 22 |
| 6 | 6 | F | 5 | O | 14 | X | 23 |
| 7 | 7 | G | 6 | P | 15 | Y | 24 |
| 8 | 8 | H | 7 | Q | 16 | Z | 25 |

- Sum both sets together
- Get the remainder of sum/26 and replace according to the table

| Remainder | Letter | Remainder | Letter | Remainder | Letter | Remainder | Letter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | 7 | H | 14 | O | 21 | V |
| 1 | B | 8 | I | 15 | P | 22 | W |
| 2 | C | 9 | J | 16 | Q | 23 | X |
| 3 | D | 10 | K | 17 | R | 24 | Y |
| 4 | E | 11 | L | 18 | S | 25 | Z |
| 5 | F | 12 | M | 19 | T |  |  |
| 6 | G | 13 | N | 20 | U |  |  |

### Input

A 16-character *codice fiscale* in the `XXXXXX00X00X000X` form.

Assume the check letter will always be a letter

### Output

Is the *Codice Fiscale* valid (the language truthy value) or not (language falsy value)?

For the purpose of the challenge, we consider a *codice fiscale* to be valid if the calculated check letter corresponds with the input's check letter.

### Examples

```
TMDVSZ30T13L528J -> true
NWWFBE83P20A181A -> false
YNFLJC39E06C956L -> true
YNFLJC39E06C956E -> false
```

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest number of bytes wins

Comment: Suggest test case where last character is number or promise it never happen

Comment: @l4m2 It will never happen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>33</s> 31 bytes

```
ØWiⱮịÐo“ÐVẈ÷{⁷.ƝİRḟ’Œ?¤’N0¦S26ḍ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wjPDMRxvXPdzdfXhC/qOGOYcnhD3c1XF4e/Wjxu16x@Ye2RD0cMf8Rw0zj06yP7QESPsZHFoWbGT2cEfvf2ugcgVdO4VHDXOtD7dzPdy95eGOTQ93LFJ51LTmcDuQiPz/P8TXJSw4ytggxNDYx9TIwgukvqSoNJXLLzzczcnVwjjAyMDR0MLQESSRlphTnMoV6efm4@VsbOlqYOZsaWrmA9eCJuEK1wIA)

A monadic link taking a string and returning 1 for valid and 0 for invalid.

### Explanation

```
ØWiⱮ                            | Index of each character in word characters (A-Aa-z0-9)
    ịÐo“ÐVẈ÷{⁷.ƝİRḟ’Œ?¤         | Index odd positions in the list into the 15593538177379092215583486‘th permutation of 1..26; leave even ones alone
                       ’        | Decrease by 1
                        N0¦     | Negate the final value
                           S    | Sum
                            26ḍ | Is divisible by 26
```

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 117 bytes

```javascript
f=([a,...x],s=i=0)=>x+x?f(x,s+g(++i%2?'BAFHJNPRTVCESULDGIMOQKWZYX'[g(a)]:a)):g(a)==s%26
g=x=>1/x?+x:parseInt(x,36)-10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hcxNC4IwAIDhe/8j3JjZ5khMWGKmlZl9WfZBh1EqRmi0iP17q2sE3d7Dw3vhTy5O9@L2aJXVOa3rjIEDVzVNk0dVsIJhyHoSSTsDUhUoBwgVTd1W@o4/CqL5Mt643modDobj6WwxSfa7rXLIAYdHi0NofYox0dSNRs4k65G2tJG0bvwu0nH5eC@pAVsE16eqFNU11a5VDjKgxNPBZrWnOCY07OhmoEDY@CJRkvh9z6RzHTvEJM4Psov8MHBp18OG2@0Y4X/ifUj9Ag)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>165</s> 159 bytes

```python
lambda s:chr((sum(ord(x)-48-17*(x>':')for x in s[1:-1:2])+sum(b"! %')-/135! %')-/135\"$24+#&(,.0*6987"[ord(x)-48-7*(x>':')]-32for x in s[:-1:2]))%26+65)==s[-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYxda8IwGEbv9yve1Y8k1mxNYmMa6EBdvZBOBoqitRdaKQqzldZB9@s7i6JeePdwnsM5/p12aSLK2F2VP@vDZruGXEe7DOP894DTbIsLQjuKsm4LFx9IIxKnGRSwTyAPmKZM85CYlbsxXqGBCH1nwr6vlVHnHbPWxO03qyUd1TWCe/TWDKngD91rljS4NKVNXDcPKAvLyogqI3gBQNOvz9lkKawpE77N1Qi1Kzqez4d9T4lvbvWYYr0LXYyH/mggHM@SA8eW/lPqnWmozwfAMdsnJxzjiJDyHw)

*-3 bytes* thanks to [@CommanderMaster's amazing observation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/269468/validate-a-codice-fiscale/269477#comment584995_269477) about removing the constant `v`!

*-3 bytes* by using multiplication instead of indexing on the condition.

---

A function that accepts a parameter `s`, which is the code to be validated.

It returns

```python
chr((S_E+S_O)%26+65)==s[-1]
```

That is, evaluates the remainder between the sum of both sets (`S_O` odd characters, `S_E` even characters) and 26, adds 65 to it (i.e. transforms a number `0-25` to `A-Z` using ASCII conversion) and checks if it's equal to the last character of the input.

`S_E` is

```python
sum(ord(x)-48-17*(x>':')for x in s[1:-1:2])
```

`x>':'` is a condition that evaluates to true (or 1) if the character `x` is a letter (since its ASCII code is higher than `:`'s). Therefore, it'll subtract 48 from the ASCII code of `x` if its numeric, otherwise it'll subtract 65. It basically maps `'0' -> 0`, ... `'9' -> 9`, `'A' -> 0`, ..., `'Z' -> 25` and sum the resulting values.

`S_O` is

```python
sum(b"! %')-/135! %')-/135\"$24+#&(,.0*6987"[ord(x)-48-7*(x>':')]-32for x in s[:-1:2])
```

If you take every ASCII code of the bytestring characters and subtract 32, you will see that it'll match the odd-characters table. So that's a transformation similar to `S_E`'s, but it now maps `'0' -> 0`, ... `'9' -> 9`, `'A' -> 10`, ..., `'Z' -> 35`, get the byte at that bytestring index and subtract 32.

Comment: I might be missing something, but removing `v` and just writing `48` twice is shorter by three bytes

Comment: @CommandMaster You haven't missed absolutely anything! That's correct, I've updated the solution

Comment: `ord(x)%65%48`?

Comment: Also subtract 52(=2*26) rather than 32 and no need to explicitly subtract

Answer (score 1):

## APL+WIN, 161 bytes

Prompts for string.

```
c←8 2⍴⎕⋄c[7;1]=a[26|+/((('BAKPLCQDREVOSFTGUHMINJWZYX'⍳c[;0])~26),(¯65+⎕av⍳'BAFHJNPRTV')[(n⍳c[;0])~10]),(((n←(⍕⍳10)~' ')⍳c[;1])~10),((a←⎕av[65+⍳26])⍳¯1↓c[;1])~26]
```

[Try it online! Thanksto Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcQJanP5BlwPWooz3tfzKQaaFg9Kh3C1DiUXdLcrS5tWGsbWK0kVmNtr6Ghoa6k6N3gI9zoEuQa5h/sFuIe6iHr6efV3hUZIT6o97NydHWBrGadUZmmjoah9abmWoDjUksA0oA9bl5ePkFBIWEqWtGa@Qh1BoCCR2gyXlAqzUe9U4FyhgaaNapK6hrQhQZghWB1CQClYANjAaZ3LvZyCwWpObQesNHbZOhKoFi/4Fe4fqfxqUe4usSFhxlbBBiaOxjamThpc4FFPQLD3dzcrUwDjAycDS0MHQEC0b6ufl4ORtbuhqYOVuamvlgE3RVBwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-pF`, 137 bytes

```perl
$c=pop@F;pairmap{$s+=$b=~s|\D|-65+ord$&|er+($a=~/\d/?1+$a*2-($a==1)+2*($a>4):BAKPLCQDREVOSFTGUHMINJWZYX=~/$a/*"@-")}@F;$_=$s%26+65==ord$c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY9dT4MwAEXf9zOWaoQGaYslDFId40PFgtOx4ZYlBrc9kOBoKG/ifrqVJT75dG9OcnNyxaGtqVJgx0QjprEnyqr9LMUXkJCBD3aS/TbsDZvCpt2Dy/7QwitQspO53Zt3GIJSJ8YZMKxBog/t9kZzZ/7TnAcv4Wu0el7E@f3yIX3MkmKzfhuGoDT18dQYa9@DDbwzIC@IDW3K2NmwUx6QDHkqT8PVYmOhHFucEicZZUURzyLHmhPkYwf7o3UW8ySwJhGygwm1@X8Q/TSiq5qjVEZKrxFGQ/JKdq677Kqa/R1VhqjjXw)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>36</s> 32 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
25Ý•D+>∞¢-‹ ŸΔŒ•.IžKIkι`Šèì`(O₂Ö
```

-4 bytes by porting [*@NickKennedy*'s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269479/52210).

Input as a list of characters.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AVAAr/9vc2FiaWX//zI1w53igKJEKz7iiJ7Coi3igLkgxbjOlMWS4oCiLknFvktJU2vOuWDFoMOow6xgKE/igoLDlv//WU5GTEpDMzlFMDZDOTU2TA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWVw6H8j08NzHzUsctG2e9Qx79Ai3UcNOxWO7jg35egkoKie59F93hHZ53YmHF1weMXhNQka/o@amg5P@6/zP1opxNclLDjK2CDE0NjH1MjCS0lHyS883M3J1cI4wMjA0dDC0BEoFOnn5uPlbGzpamDmbGlq5oMp5KoUCwA).

**Explanation:**

```python
25Ý              # Push a list in the range [0,25]
   •D+>∞¢-‹ ŸΔŒ• # Push compressed integer 15593538177379092215583485
     .I          # Get the (0-based) 15593538177379092215583485th permutation of the [0,25]-list:
                 #  [1,0,5,7,9,13,15,17,19,21,2,4,18,20,11,3,6,8,12,14,16,10,22,25,24,23]
žK               # Push constant "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
  Ik             # Get the (0-based) index of each character of the input in this string
    ι            # Uninterleave it into two parts
     `           # Pop and push both parts to the stack
      Š          # Triple-swap the three lists on the stack
       è         # Index the 0-based even indices into the permuted list
        ì        # Prepend-merge the two lists back together
         `       # Pop and push all integers separated to the stack
          (      # Negate the last one
           O     # Sum all integers on the stack together
            ₂Ö   # Check whether this sum is divisible by 26
                 # (after which it is output implicitly as result)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to compress large integers?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `•D+>∞¢-‹ ŸΔŒ•` is `15593538177379092215583485`.
The `15593538177379092215583485` is generated using Jelly's \$n^{th}\$ permutation builtin `œ¿`: [try it online](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///o5EP7////7@To5uHlFxAUEubsGhzq4@Lu6esf6B0eFRnx39HJ2cXVzd3D08vbx9fPPyAwKDgkNCw8IjIKAA) (minus 1, because 05AB1E uses 0-based indexing and Jelly 1-based indexing).

Comment: I didn’t know 05AB1E had a permutation built-in like Jelly. Your Jelly comment TIO link is slightly off - `Œ¿` is monadic so is just finding the permutation number for the sorted first argument. `œ¿` is what you meant if you’re looking for the dyadic version, though here the result is identical because the second argument **is** the sorted version of the first one!

Comment: @NickKennedy Woops, I copied the wrong Jelly builtin. Fixed it. And yes, 05AB1E's `.I` is equivalent to Jelly's `œ?`, but unfortunately it only works on lists.

Answer (score 0):

## Excel ms365, 199 bytes

Assuming input in `A1`:

```
=CHAR(MOD(SUM(MAP(ROW(1:15),LAMBDA(i,TOROW(FIND(MID(A1,i,1),IF(ISODD(i),{"10   2 3 4   5 6 7 8 9","BAKPLCQDREVOSFTGUHMINJWZYX"},{"0123456789","ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"})),3)-1))),26)+65)=RIGHT(A1)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Funge-98](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Funge-98), 108 bytes

```
"NRTS"4(I'0>'v00p
<@.!-+A'g20w1p21-1:g21p20%'+g20+-fg3-+0'*'`9':\-+0'*'`9':

 "$!#%('&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz//9X8gsKCVYy0fBUN7BTLzMwKOCycdBT1NV2VE83Mig3LDAy1DW0SjcCMgxUpdS1gYLaumnpxrraBupaguoJlupWMUhsLgYOLgF@ETEJGTkFJRVBYUVlKSFRcWlZeUlVDXW1//9DfF3CgqOMDUIMjX1MjSy8uAA)

Contains non-printable characters, so here is a hex dump:

```
00000000: 224e 5254 5322 3428 4927 303e 2776 3030  "NRTS"4(I'0>'v00
00000010: 700a 3c40 2e21 2d2b 4127 6732 3077 3170  p.<@.!-+A'g20w1p
00000020: 3231 2d31 3a67 3231 7032 3025 1a27 2b67  21-1:g21p20%.'+g
00000030: 3230 2b2d 6667 332d 2b30 272a 1127 6039  20+-fg3-+0'*.'`9
00000040: 273a 5c2d 2b30 272a 1127 6039 273a 0a00  ':\-+0'*.'`9':..
00000050: 080a 100f 1416 181c 1e20 2224 1113 2123  ......... "$..!#
00000060: 1a12 1517 1b1d 1f19 2528 2726            ........%('&
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 50 bytes

```
ＦＳ⊞υ⌕⁺α⭆χκι¬﹪⁻⊟υΣＥυ⎇﹪κ²ι⌕α§”$⌈⊟⌈σEζ⊖)"⁷hＹ✂&⊕⧴C”ι²⁶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY3LCsIwEEX3fkVwNYEI2qIIrnxbNRptfXUXbNViTUpMRL8@pj5mMzBzzz3HC1dHyXNrT1IhCERhdKhVJs6AMWLmfgFD0CgTCbDc3IET9H1TXkCjTtAVY4IyjDsV5s4aFlIDlYnJJdBMOILJAozLhOYGJeTqolQJrl7/3JUgryz5eZyiqwORpE@o9rqjyXTB1tG2Pww388E4oMvVbBcf9tWPtRxHt9zqWBvRwTaM/XrU8OdNrz21tUf@Bg) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs a Charcoal boolean, i.e. `-` for a valid code, nothing if not. Explanation:

```
ＦＳ⊞υ⌕⁺α⭆χκι
```

Loop through the input string, converting each character into its index in the string `A..Z0..9`.

```
¬﹪⁻⊟υΣＥυ⎇﹪κ²ι⌕α§”...”ι²⁶
```

Remove the last value, permute alternate elements (permutation string shamelessly stolen from @Arnauld's answer), take the sum, and compare the the removed last value modulo 26.